# How can I align a buffer on the stack?

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded

I'm trying to achieve a memory buffer that's aligned by it's size so I can use the modulo feature of a DMA controller to implement a ring buffer.  I know I can do this with memalign, but I'm wondering if its possible to do so on the stack as so far I've been able to **avoid dynamic memory**.  I'm using GCC 4.4.1 and I don't care about portability (embedded system).

I want to do something like:

```
template<uint16_t num_channels, uint16_t buffer_size>
class sampler {
    __attribute__((aligned(buffer_size * num_channels * 2)))
    uint16_t buffer[buffer_size][num_channels];
};
```

but of course GCC won't accept non-constant alignment (and seems to indicate that alignments > 8 may not be honored anyway).

I think I could use C++0x alignas() to achieve this, but it doesn't seem to appear in GCC until version 4.8.

I guess one option might be to double the size of the buffer, but that seems to waste a bunch of space (I'm planning on trying to use a substantial fraction of the device memory for this buffer).  Maybe I should just give up and use dynamic memory.  Is memalign going to be relatively efficient in terms of wasted space?

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need such a weird alignment (the buffer's size)? Typical alignments needed are either for some basic type (int,__m128), a page (usually 4KB), or a page allocation granularity (usually 64KB on Windows, dunno how or if your controller does it).

Comment: Probably because it simplifies the DMA operation's wrapping logic.  When your memory is also to be accessed by the simplistic hardware state machine that is a DMA controller, additional constraints come into play.

Comment: Have you considered putting the buffer in its own translation unit and then using linker directives to force alignment or starting address for that unit?  If you want it on the stack I think you need to allocate double the buffer size.  memalign() will use the space wasted by alignment to fulfill other memory allocation requests.

Comment: This is on ARM Cortex M4 (actually a [teensy 3](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/paulstoffregen/teensy-30-32-bit-arm-cortex-m4-usable-in-arduino-a)) with no MMU.

Comment: @brianbeuning Re: "linker directives" I'd guess I'd have to pick a buffer size in the .ld file?  If not, could you describe further?  One of my longer term goals was to produce an Arduino library usable by others, so the template was really attractive because users could easily specify the sizes in their own projects.

Comment: Does anyone know if alignas() would infact do this for me if it was available (looks like C++11)?  Or does it max out at some value (like attribute align)?  Thanks for all the discussion by the way this is really helpful!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to double the storage's size, you only need to add `(alignment - 1)` to it -- basically the same thing that `memalign` does behind the scenes. For a power of two alignment:

```
char buf[size + (alignment -1)];
char *aligned = (char*)((intptr_t)buf + (alignment - 1) & ~intptr_t(alignment - 1));
```

Comment: That was my thought too, however I think the alignment size is the same as the buffer size in this case, so this method would require 1 less than twice the buffer size.

Comment: @Chris In which case you are not really wasting much memory to begin with. And there really isn't anything you can do, the `sp` will have a specific value when you call it and worst case that means adding `alignment - 1` to the current value and basically waste it. You could compute how much you have to waste to get aligned dynamically and then allocate the array dynamically on the stack, but that's about it.

Comment: @Voo Did you mean to say "allocate the array dynamically on the heap" here? If not, can you elaborate?  I basically do want the compiler to "compute how much space to waste" (or be smart about placement to minimize wastage).

Comment: @Christopher No I really meant stack. Variable length arrays on the stack are part of the C99 standard but not of C++11. But most compilers support them with their own extensions too, g++ certainly does (and in this case VLAs don't make any more problems than fixed size arrays already do). Will save you some memory in some circumstances, but in the worst case you will have to waste `alignment - 1` memory no way around this.

Comment: @Voo Oh, I see what you mean; I guess I'm already doing this via the template.  So essentially you're suggesting doubling the size of the buffer and the computing the alignment.

Comment: @Christopher No there's a difference between the size of the array (which is what you specify with your template) and the actual value of the stackpointer when the function is called. The necessary alignment depends on the value of the stackpointer. But yes even if you get a compiler to do the alignment for you, it can't do much more than what you're already doing (it could rearrange the locals to minimize the wasted space)

Comment: Obviously that only applies to local storage. If you use a chunk of global memory, you may be able to avoid wasting memory, but you can't use it for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since I have used linker command files but I think it would go like this.

Create file buffer.cpp with

```
char buffer[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
```

An object file has sections named .bss (for uninitialized data), .data (for initialized data), and .text (for executable code).
buffer[] will go in .bss since it is not initialized.

So a (gnu) linker file like this should do the trick

```
SECTIONS {
   .bss 0x0  : {
        buffer.o(.bss)
        *(.bss)
    }
   .data : {
        *(.data)
    }
   .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

The 0x0 tells the linker to load buffer[] at address 0x0.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a buffer bigger than `buffer_size` and then calculate an offset in it to begin from?

Answer (score 0):

If your embedded system has a memory management unit, there's little need to fear judicious use of dynamic memory, especially if you only allocate once per run.

If it does not have an MMU, you could consider assigning a fixed location with the linker map file.

On systems with an actual operating system, DMA-compatible buffers may have to be specially allocated by the kernel anyway.